# CSS: If div with class exists within p tag, then do something

Tags: css, conditional-statements

Okay let's go wild. Is it possible to check a condition using CSS like this:

If div with class `hello` exists **within** `<p>` tag, then add styling to the `<p>` tag.

So:

```
<p>
  <div class="hello"> world </div>
</p>
```

So I want to target and add styling to the `<p>` tag, **not** the div tag.

Comment: No, there is no parent selector in CSS.

Comment: And, at least in X/HTML, a div cannot exist inside a p. (But even if you were working with some other markup language that allows a div within a p, the above comment still holds true.)

Comment: @BoltClock The usage of div within the p tag was only an example to discuss the concept.